# Why is the openquery returning 0 rows on SQL server but has 900k rows in the target Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server, openquery

Need help to figure ut why the remote query I execute on the server return 0 rows , but the same query returns over 900k rows in the target DB.

the string is less 8000 characters long so I won't post it here.  but this is the sctructure basically:

```
declare @SQL varchar(MAX);
declare @D varchar(15);
declare @Per varchar(15);
declare @NextPer varchar(15);
declare @NextYPer varchar(15);
set @D = N'01-JUN-2019'
set @Per = N'2020004';
set @NextYPer = N'2021004'
set @NextPer = N'2020005'
set @SQL = N' SELECT  ...... '
set @SQL = N'select * from openquery ([LK1], "'+@SQL+'")';
execute( @SQL);
print @SQL;
```

Note: the linked server works and is used on other openqueries with shorter strings successfully. I tried using EXECUTE (@SQL) AT  and I still get 0 rows.  When i exexute the print output directly on the Oracle DB , the query runs for about 15 min and gives results.

Comment: I guess this is on SQL Server? Please tag it appropriately

Comment: I wouldn't expect to see double quotes `"` used in your `OPENQUERY` statement - surely that won't even work. To make any progress you need to reduce the issue to a minimum example that exhibits the error. In the process you'll probably find the error yourself

Comment: The user you use to access the linked server need not be the same as the one you use to execute queries directly, and that could easily lead to discrepancies. Check the credentials/mappings configured for the `LK1` server (in the process, you should also be able to double check that you've got the right server). Also, try simplifying the query until it does produce some sort of result, then work back up to the full form to see where things change.

Comment: Thanks both. I'm maybe getting closer. when I run a subquery of the original query in the same way, it also returns 0 rows. However, I tried it after commenting out the @D Parameter in the where clause, and it suddenly returned rows. I'm experimenting some more with the parameters and will see what gives.

Comment: Suspect is that `01-JUN-2019` is the only value that can't make sense unless properly quoted (unlike something like `2021004`, which works as an integral constant). Per TT's answer, check if you've got a possible quoting issue, or an implicit conversion to a date/time type that doesn't survive the link. (For SQL Server itself, the only safe, locale-independent form of this constant is `20190601` if it has to be implicitly converted, but Oracle has more flexible parsing functions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the input.

The root cause is simply the format of the Date parameter, which didn't run correctly on the linked server.
All I had to do is change my query to use this:

**SO_BOOK_DATE <  to_date(''@D''  , ''DD-MON-YYYY'')**

instead of

**SO_BOOK_DATE < ''@D''  .**

Answer (score 0):

First off, `OPENQUERY` requires the second parameter to be a query string. A string in SQL Server is written between single quotes. From [OPENQUERY documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql):

```
OPENQUERY ( linked_server ,'query' )
```

Not only that, the SQL that appears in that string, needs to have any single-quotes that appear in the query to be doubled. Suppose you had SQL you wanted to execute the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE name='TT.';
```

You would write this as:

```
OPENQUERY(lks,'SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE name=''TT.''')
```

But if you have this in a dynamic SQL statement, this would become

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @s='SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(lks,''SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE name=''''TT.'''''')';
```

So that's some explosion of single quotes for even the more trivial SQL queries. Count ye quotes, make sure the query itself is up to snuff (i.e. quotes have been properly doubled).

Comment: Yes, I agree on the hassle it takes for having too many single quotes. I was playing around with everything trying to find a solution. thanks for replying.